# From many arrays to one array

Tags: jquery, arrays

Hi at this moment I have many arrays and each array contains data of 1 input field. So it looks like this:

[image]

In the browser it looks like this (link if the picture is too small: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JC0i8.png) :
[image]

This happens because I use the serialize() method to get all the input of my form. But gladly what I want to have is an array that looks something like this:

```
Array([load_id_task]=> 1, [load_ot_hour]=> 2, [load_hour_ot_salaries]=>100, [load_ot_total_salaries] => 200)

Array([load_id_task]=> 80, [load_ot_hour]=> 6, [load_hour_ot_salaries]=>20, [load_ot_total_salaries] => 120)
```

This is the piece of code that I currently use:

```
/*
SAVING THE DATA OF AN ORDER
*/
    $('#saveOrder').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $('#orderForm');
        var data = Array();
        //var data = { id: [44 ] };
/*
        $("#taskTable tr").each(function(i, v){
            data[i] = Array();

             var $this = $(this);
                var rowId = $this.data('row');
                $hour =  $("#hour_ot" + rowId);
               hour= $hour.val();
               // console.log("hour val"+ JSON.stringify($hour));   
                console.log("hour val"+ hour);  
            $(this).children('td').each(function(ii, vv){
                //data[i][ii] = $(this).text();

                data[i][ii] = $(this).text();
            }); 
        }) */

        //var values = $("#hour_ot1, #hour_ot_salary1, #total_ot_salary1").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
        //$('#firstname,#lastname,#password').map(function () {return this.value; }).get();

        var allInput=form.serialize();
        //var allInputJSON = JSON.stringify(allInput);

        //console.log('form serialize value:  '+form.serialize());
        //console.log('allInputJSON value:  '+allInputJSON);

        $.ajax( {
              type: "POST",
              url: absUrl + "/user/orders/update/order",
              data: {'allInput' : allInput},
              success: function( response ) {

              var response = $.parseJSON(response);

               $('#errors').empty();
                $.each(response, function(index, value) {
                    $( '#order-succes p' ).remove();

                    if(value=="De offerte is succesvol geüpdate."){
                        $('#order-succes').append(
                        '<p>'+
                        value
                        +
                        '</p>');
                    }else{
                        $('#errors').append(
                            '<p>'+
                            value
                            +
                            '</p>');    
                    }
                });
```

As you can see I was already thinking about creating an array, but I couldn't think further to what I have to do.. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: An array doesn't have named items. An array is also an object, which is why you can add properties (named items) to it, but you should use an object instead of an array.

Comment: It's relatively simple to run a loop in php to create structure you want.